# difficulty in entering correct script for dateformat

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

this is my query

```
SELECT Fullname, rank, id_no, TIN, birthdate, 
hair, eyes, Blood, height, weight, marks, name, address
FROM  [******_DOMAIN\****_*****].*******view
```

I want to change the dateformat default from `yyyymmdd` to `mm/dd/yyyy`, but I'm having difficulties writing the correct script for changing dateformat.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: sorry i was using ms sql 2008 and "dateformat"

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR,dateColumn,101)
from your TableName
```

3rd argument here could be any supported format numeral.

For more info [Go here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: I have changed 3rd argument from `108` to `101` this will give you `MM/DD/YYYY` format, But for more formats you can go to the link that I have given under my answer.\

Comment: i tried using that also, still does not work, can it be that the date is locked?

Comment: What is the datatype of your datecolumn ??

Comment: char 8 that what it says in the properties